# I am not able to set interval in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my showdate.js  - >

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Showdate extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        setInterval(1000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to GeeksforGeeks!</h1>
                <h2>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Showdate;
```

and rendering through index.js as ->

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Showdate from "./showDate";
const rootElement4 = document.getElementById("root4");
console.log(<Showdate />);
ReactDOM.render(<Showdate />, rootElement4);
```

time is getting displayed but it is not refresshing by one sec as it should acc to setinterval(1000)

Comment: setInterval() takes a callback function that you have not provided. I suggest you read the documentation to see how to use it correctly.

Comment: The way you have used `setInterval` is NOT correct.

Comment: Hi @muralcode, It's best to describe with more detail the goal that you wanted to achieve with this piece of code, so the community can help you

Answer (score 1):

You must do something like this:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.state = {
       myTime: new Date() //Initialize your state
    }
}
componentDidMount() { //Use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount

    this.myInterval = setInterval(()=>this.tick(), 1000); //Provide a callback to setInterval
}
tick(){

  this.setState({myTime: new Date()})
}


 componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.myInterval); //You must clear interval when the component is unmounted; otherwise it could lead to memory leakage 
  }
```

Then Use `myTime` in your JSX
  `<h2>{this.state.myTime.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>`

Answer (score 0):

you can this :

```
this.timerChronoId = setInterval(() => {
                this.setState({
                    time: (this.state.time + 1)
                });
            }, 1000);
```

you can use **this.timerChronoId** after to pause the timer by calling :

```
clearInterval(this.timerChronoId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `setInterval` is taking a callback function and the timeout. So, you have to implement it as follows. Plus, you should clear the interval before your component is unmounted.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

    class Showdate extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { date: new Date() }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          this.timer = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000)
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
          clearInterval(this.timer)
        }

        tick() {
          this.setState({ date: new Date() })
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Welcome to GeeksforGeeks!</h1>
                    <h2>{this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Showdate;
```